# Highlight and space out tags in org-mode

Tags: emacs, tags, elisp, org-mode

I would like to change the way tags are displayed in the org-mode buffer from this:

* Headline                                                         **:tag1:tag2:tag3:**

to this:

* Headline `tag1` `tag2` `tag3`

So basically, the changes I'm looking for are:

1. Start tags immediately after the headline.
2. Hide the `:` characters
3. Add a space in-between each tag, so that long lists of tags will wrap properly in `visual line mode`
4. Remove default bold formatting of tags and add a highlight

So far, I've been able to change the font face and add a highlight by customizing the `Org Tag` property. As a temp/hack, I made the `:` characters invisible by turning on `hi-lock-mode` and then `M-x highlight-phrase [RET] : [RET] org-hide [RET]`. But this only hides the colon—it doesn't actually create a real space. So tags still won't wrap properly in `visual line mode`. Also, this hides all colons, everywhere, not just the ones that separate tags.

Perhaps another option is to add the space but leave the colon?

* Headline `:tag1` `:tag2` `:tag3`

I've been auditioning this with the solarized-light theme. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas, comments? Thanks!

Comment: In terms of preventing right alignment of tags, you can use `(setq org-tags-column 0)`.  As to the other stuff, I'll leave that to another forum participant.  If you put spaces, you may be in for a world of hurt as a regexp is used to locate and deal with tags.  I don't think the tag regexp `\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)` contemplates spaces, so you'll experience unforeseen consequences if you try to put spaces.

Comment: In terms of the font face, place your cursor on wherever a particular font exists and type `C-u C-x =` and that will tell you want font is present.  You can then use `M-x customize-face` to customize the applicable font.  When you get more advanced, you can edit the font face modifications by hand in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file.  As to your wrapping issue, you could use "notes" below the property drawers and keep your headline simple so that it doesn't wrap.  Once you become more accustomed to org-mode, you'll probably appreciate the colons and forget about wanting to hide them.

Comment: You can do almost anything with any text by the `display` text property. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html I think this could be used in `org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook`. (Not sure about this.)

Comment: Tobias, thanks! Unfortunately, I know absolutely zip about elisp... how would you implement this?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @lawlist, the `(setq org-tags-column 0)` puts the tags immediately after headline.

To hide the colons associated with tags, I tried the approach suggested by @Tobias, by setting the display property of `:`. Putting this snippet in `.emacs` or `init.el` seems to work for me.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
  '(("^\\*+ "
     ":" nil nil
     (0 (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) 'display " ")))))
```

I was referring to the `(matcher . anchored-highlighter)` format of setting a [Search-based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification):

- the `"^\\*+ "` part first matches an org heading
- the subsequent `":"` searches for `:`
- the next line replaces the matched `:` with a space, according to the doc on [display specs that replaces the texts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html#Replacing-Specs)

A screenshot (note I didn't set `org-tags-column 0` so it aligns right, and the font coloring are set by `customize-face RET org-tag RET`):
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for `org-mode` but not for `org-agenda-mode`, which uses `text-properties` rather than `fontify`.

Comment: After further investigation, this works if `org-agenda-show-inherited-tags` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for could be solved if:

- there was a face org-tag-separator (for example) just for the ":" symbol,
- you customized that face to have its foreground equal to your background.

To ask on the Org ML?